# Java Date validation

Tags: java

I have to display a page only if the following condition is satisfied i.e

```
if(system_date >=start_date){
 if(system_date<=End_date){
  //Do some thing
 }
}
```

Say for example `start_date = 08-03-2011` and `end_date = 10-03-2011`.

I am not able to figure this out. kindly help.

Comment: What's your actual problem? Parsing the dates? Writing the comparison logic?

Comment: Actually i am getting start and end date from database in dd-MM-yyyy format and had to compare with system date

Answer (score 3):

```
Date now = new Date();
if ((now.after(startDate) || now.equals(startDate)) && ((now.before.endDate) || now.equals(endDate))
{
    // do something
}
```

I agree that Joda Time is very good, but you'll have to weigh whether this simple requirement is worth another JAR dependency.  Sometimes you just need something simple.

Comment: Unless I had a *really* good reason not to take any dependencies, I'd include Joda as soon as I had pretty much *any* date/time work to do. What's the cost of an extra jar file vs the readability benefits of having an API which is so much better designed?

Comment: @Jon - I would agree, but I might be tempted to hold off if the stated requirement is the only date/time work that's needed.

Comment: Except that we've seen there's parsing involved - which is more easily done using Joda's thread-safe formatters, etc...

Comment: Parsing?  The question that I'm reading says the dates are fetched from a database.  I'd hope that they were returned as java.util.Date instead of String.  If so, no parsing required.

Answer (score 1):

As OrangeDog suggests, I'd use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net).

You can create a `DateTime` or an `Instant` for the start dates and end dates, then use something like:

```
if (startDate.isBeforeNow() && endDate.isAfterNow())
```

or perhaps

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(); // Possibly provide time zone etc if you want
if (startDate.compareTo(now) <= 0 && now.compareTo(endDate) <= 0)
```

Or even:

```
Interval valid = new Interval(startDate, endDate);
if (valid.containsNow())
```

Basically you've got lots of options depending on your exact requirements :)

Comment: For now Joda is the only sound replacement for standard date related classes. And along with many utility functions it's far superior and still easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an external lib, you can use `Calendar`'s `setTime()` to create a Calendar out of a given date and then use `compareTo` to compare two calendar instances.

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setTime(startDate);

Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
current.setTime(systemDate);

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setTime(endDate);

if (current.compareTo(start) > 0 && current.compareTo(end) < 0) {
    //Do some thing
}
```

Of course, you have to take care of Timezones and Locales when creating the Calendar instances.